# Python : replacing words while iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why this code is not working. I am trying to iterate over a copy of a list of words and replace the words with another given word. Instead I am getting raised invalid syntax errors. I understand now (from reading other posts on here) that modifying lists while iterating is bad practise, therefore I created a copy using `[:]`.  Here is the code I have:

`def change(z):
    words = z.split()
    for i in words[:]:
        if 'because' in i:
            words.replace(i, 'as')
    print(words)
change(input("Line: "))`

And the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jarrod/Desktop/py/NCSS2016Adv/kindleNook.py", line 9, in <module>
    change(input("Line: "))
  File "<string>", line 1
    is as
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Any clues to why my syntax is incorrect would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation is off... Indent everything below `def`. Also, post the error message with full traceback next time.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to this. I'll fix this up :)

Comment: @Lafexlos The question is about syntax errors. Still this shows very minimal understanding.

Comment: `print(z.replace("as","because"))` is all you need

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: Post the full code, your trace seems to show error at different line

Comment: @adep7 You should post your *actual* code, not a hypothetical one that does *not* have the same errors as the actual code.

Comment: Jee I'm bad at this, think I've posted ALL of the code this time. Didn't format correctly the first time so I accidentally deleted the call.

Comment: @adep7 This can't possibly be "ALL" the code as there isn't 9 lines in this sample. The error clearly says line 9 of a file in the trace-back. What other files are in your project, are you importing them?

Comment: You're not doing the replacement properly. @Chris_Rands posted what you need to fix.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks! I'll give it a go now. Not too sure why I'm writing all this excess code when something that simple is glaring infront of me. Sorry to everyone else for my poor work getting this post together.

Comment: @Oasiscircle Sorry about that, when I use the ` to mark code and place two lines between code and my call the call is not included in the actual code but by itself.

Comment: You have tagged your question as `python-3.x`. Are you *__ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN*__ that this is the version you're using?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, most definitely. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Really, really, *__really__* certain? Because the interpreter attempting to evaluate code on `input()` happens in Python 2, not 3. So, again: are you sure you're sure?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should give a code that actually creates the error you get, as stated from other people in the comments.

Anyway, in your code, `i` will be a string, not a list, because you are iterating the list from `split` with your loop. So, maybe you should use `if i == 'because'` rather than `if 'because' in i`?

Comment: It's really impossible to speculate what the author truly wants out of this function because of how horribly broken the code is. Perhaps they really want 'because' to be replaced if it's in the string not just if it equals the string, but who knows?

Comment: @Oasiscircle, ah that makes sense, sorry for all this, I should include all these details when posting. What I really want to do is only replace the string if it equates it not if it is in the string. Thanks

Comment: Changing a membership check to an equality check couldn't possibly resolve a `SyntaxError`. I don't know why this is accepted. @adep7, did it actually resolve the issue? Because, uh, it's kind of impossible for it to have done so.

Comment: Seconded @TigerhawkT3, this answer could not have solved the issue and should not be accepted.

Answer (score -2):

Do you use Python 2.x or 3.x ? If 2.x:

Python 2 built-in `input()` function will try to interpret the input string as python code: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

So if you input it natural language it will obviously provoke invalid syntax errors.

Use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Downvoters, I'm pretty sure that my answer is the correct answer, so please explain why you think otherwise...

Comment: input() doesn't interpret as Python code. eval() and exec() do.

Comment: I have the feeling that the OP mistagged the question and is not using the version of Python they think they're using.

Comment: in Python 2 it does (link to doc in my initial post). And that perfectly matches what is going on here. Same feeling as @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @Guillaume Author tagged the question as Python 3.x, that's all we can go on until they check that the version is actually the one they're using or not.

Comment: The error is a Python 2 error. I think it might be reasonable to go by the posted traceback.

Comment: I'd say the error is a symptom of accidentally using the wrong environment. Kind of like asking someone on the street "what time does the train arrive?" and you can't understand what they're saying because it's in German. But the problem isn't that you need to learn some German, it's _how did you end up in Germany when you thought you were in the United States?_